# Sending a parameter from user control that uses a custom control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I want to pass a parameter from a User Control that uses a Custom Control, and use that on my Custom Control's cs. For example, if I had a Custom Control on a UserControl

In UserControl (e.g. ThisViewName.XAML):

```
<ctrl:PinWindowControl Tag="ThisViewName" Grid.Row="0"/>
```

Which pretty much just contains a button

Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PinWindowControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:PinWindowControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Button Width="100" Height="100"></Button>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can I get the Tag all the way to my PinWindowControl.cs file?

Comment: How come you have Tag in xaml but not in the control ! thts strange. did you check with this.Tag? It is a property of frameworkElement.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the tag myself. It doesn't have to be a Tag property but I just need to get "ThisViewName" (which is the actual name of the View) all the way to my Custom Control :)

Comment: did you check Parent property?

Comment: @Nikita parent seems to be null from the CS

Comment: can you add code for tag property. How have you defined it

Comment: Thanks for your help @Nikita! I'm marking lll 's as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you created a `DependencyProperty` in your `PinWindowControl`:

You can access `Tag` using `this.Tag`. Your `PinWindowControl` is a `partial class` that is associated with your `XAML`.

```
public class PinWindowControl.cs : FrameworkElement
{
  public PinWindowControl()
  {
     Debug.WriteLine(this.Tag);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by creating a DependencyProperty...I can access the this.Tag from PinWindowControl.cs, but it's null! :\

Comment: DependencyProperty is when you create a property that can be bindable on your custom control. Again I was just assuming so I guess it's just a normal property. When are you trying to access this.Tag?

Comment: I followed your example and was getting null for everything. Apparently everything's okay if I get this.Tag and any DependencyProperty outside of the constructor :P. Thanks so much!